# Can I define secretStoreRef's name of a ExternalSecret in my configMap?

Tags: kustomize, external-secrets-operator

I have an `ExternalSecret` definition pulling secrets from Azure key vault.

```
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ExternalSecret
  name: my-es
spec:
  dataFrom:
    - find:
    ... copy some values over
  secretStoreRef:
    kind: SecretStore
    name: my-special-store        <-- This is the name I want to pull from my config map
```

The thing is that the above store is the same across all my environments apart from the `secretStoreRef.Name`. Hence I have to redefine an ExternalSecret in each environment. Not the whole thing but I do have to override the name.

Each environment already has a config map. Is there no way to add the name in the `ConfigMap` and somehow reference it from withing in the ExternalSecret defintion?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-cm
data:
  val: value1
  my_special_secret_store_name: my-special-store     <-- Can I not define my secret store name here and use it in the ExternalSecret
```

I know there is a way of using `yq` but I do not have `yq` available and all kustomise configs in one file separated by `---` per environment aka i do not have a configmap.yaml.
`$(cat configmap.yaml | yq eval '.data.myVaultName' -)`

Is there a way to pull the name from the configMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can patch the resource using kustomize. Given an input of:

```
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: my-es
spec:
  dataFrom:
    - find:
  secretStoreRef:
    kind: SecretStore
    name: original-name
```

If you use the following `kustomization.yaml`:

```
resources:
  - externalsecret.yaml

patches:
  - patch: |
      apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
      kind: ExternalSecret
      metadata:
        name: my-es
      spec:
        secretStoreRef:
          name: my-special-store
```

The output of `kustomize build` will be:

```
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: my-es
spec:
  dataFrom:
  - find: null
  secretStoreRef:
    kind: SecretStore
    name: my-special-store
```

Comment: I am accepting this as an answer as this is the only other way I found doing it. But I think just repeating the `ExternalSecret` is less code than doing this